# Download pdfs with python pt.2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, web-scraping

I am trying to download several PDFs which are located in different hyperlinks in a single URL. I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937985/download-pdfs-with-python) but this URL has a different structure. The URLs that contain the PDF's has the text "*p_p_col_count%3D*" which is included in the code, but for some reason it does not work.

There is another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237311/downloading-pdfs-from-links-scraped-with-beautiful-soup), but here the web page has (in my opinion) a nice well structured HTML code, while the page that I am trying to scrape has 12 crammed lines of code. Moreover the PDF's in the solution web page can be downloaded in a single link while in my case you need to identify the proper URLs and then download them.

This is "my" code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.contraloria.gov.co/web/guest/resultados/proceso-auditor/auditorias-liberadas/sector-infraestructura-fisica-y-telecomunicaciones-comercio-exterior-y-desarrollo-regional/auditorias-liberadas-infraestructura-2019'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("table.table > tbody.table-data td.first > a[href*='p_p_col_count%3D']"):
        inner_link = item.get("href")
        resp = s.get(inner_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
        pdf_link = soup.select_one("a.taglib-icon:contains('Descargar')").get("href")
        file_name = pdf_link.split("/")[-2].split("/")[-1]
        with open(f"{file_name}.pdf","wb") as f:
            f.write(s.get(pdf_link).content)
```

Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237311/downloading-pdfs-from-links-scraped-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading PDFs from links scraped with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237311/downloading-pdfs-from-links-scraped-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Hi I replaced the URL and it did not downloaded the documents, the HTML structure is quite different. I am not an HTML expert but the UK Companies House is nicely coded compared with the page I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with the `CSS` selectors, also there's some room to improve handling of the file names, as they not so easy to unify.

You might what to try this:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.contraloria.gov.co/web/guest/resultados/proceso-auditor/auditorias-liberadas/sector-infraestructura-fisica-y-telecomunicaciones-comercio-exterior-y-desarrollo-regional/auditorias-liberadas-infraestructura-2019'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(link).text, "lxml")
    follow_links = [
        link["href"] for link
        in soup.select(".aui .asset-abstract .asset-content .asset-more a")
    ]

    for follow_link in follow_links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(follow_link).text, "lxml")
        pdf_link = soup.select_one(
            ".aui .view .lfr-asset-column-details .download-document a"
        ).get("href")
        pdf_response = s.get(pdf_link)
        pdf_name = pdf_response.headers["Content-Disposition"]
        file_name = "_".join(
            unquote(
                re.split(r"\d{3}", pdf_name, 1)[-1]
            ).split()
        ).replace('"', "")
        print(f"Fetching {file_name}")
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(pdf_response.content)
```

Output:

```
Fetching Actuación_Especial_Contrato_de_Concesión_del_Aeropuerto_El_Dorado.pdf
Fetching ACTUACION_ESPECIAL_DE_FISCALIZACI+ôN_FONDO_DE_ADAPTACION-PUENTE_HISGAURA_MALAGA_LOS_CUROS.pdf
Fetching ACTUACION_ESPECIAL_DE_CONTROL_FISCAL_SERVICIOS_POSTALES_NACIONALES_S.A._472.pdf
Fetching Actuación_Especial_de_Control_Fiscal_-Convenios_suscritos_por_la_Agencia_Nacional_Inmobiliaria_Virgilio_Barco_Vargas.pdf
Fetching Cumplimiento_Superintendencia_de_Transporte.pdf
Fetching Cumplimiento_ANI-_Corredor_Vial_Bogota-Villavicencio.pdf
Fetching Financiera_Cámara_de_Comercio_de_Armenia_y_del_Quind+¡o.pdf
...
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, I managed to download the first 2 pdf's but there was error here `---> 26         with open(file_name, "wb") as f:` with this document `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'ACTUACION_ESPECIAL_DE_CONTROL_FISCAL_SERVICIOS_POSTALES_NACIONALES_S.A._472.pdf"'`. I know that you managed to download the documents, probably it can be a codification issue on my side.

Comment: This probably has something to do with the `"` in the file name. Those files names are terribly formatted. I've updated the answer, try now.

Comment: Thank you I managed to download the documents. Regarding the web page I guess that the HTML code is a mess also.